# Angular Material Data Table not displayed

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hi I have the following problem. I made an Angular Material table as in the example provided on the [documentation site](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview). My problem is now the table is rendered and also the right amount of rows is rendered but no columns and no data is displayed.

```
<div class="app-errors">
   <div class="spinner-container" *ngIf="dataSource.loading$ | async">
     <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
   </div>
   <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
     <ng-container matColumnDef="seqNo" >
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>#</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">{{data.id}}</mat-cell>
     </ng-container>

     <mat-header-row  *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
     <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
   </mat-table></div>
```

Rendered:

```
<app-errors _nghost-c4="" class="ng-star-inserted">
 <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="app-errors">
   <!---->
   <mat-table _ngcontent-c4="" class="mat-table" role="grid"><!----><!---->
      <mat-row _ngcontent-c4="" class="mat-row ng-star-inserted" role="row">
           <!---->
      </mat-row>
   </mat-table>
  </div>
 </app-errors>
```

Comment: are you getting data in dataSource???

Comment: yes data is in the dataSource. Tried it the way it should work later with a rest request to retrieve the data but also tried it with a local array of data but i get the same result rows are correct but columns and data not

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Created a new project with the exact same configuration copied everything in there now it works. Very strange behavior